# How to convert QString to std::chrono

Tags: c++, qt, stl, std, c++-chrono

I have a task to make a function, which will convert time objects (QString type)  to std::chrono::milliseconds. The format, which should be processed is

`QString("HH:MM:SS DD-MM-YYYY")` to `std::chrono::milliseconds`

I searched for answers before here [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58318415/how-do-i-set-a-specific-time-using-the-stdchrono-library), and in other sources in google.
In result, I have written this code, and its correct, but I am totally confused how it works. The questions are:

- Why do I have to subtract `chronoUserTime - chronoEpochTime` instead of using `chronoUserTime`  ?
- Are there any ways, to perfome this in direct way, like in Qt style `addDays`, `setTime`, etc ?

---

```
const std::chrono::milliseconds &xml_order_base::converter(QString dateTime)
{
   char *dateChar = const_cast<char*>(dateTime.toStdString().c_str());
   std::tm ct;
   strptime(dateChar, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &ct);
   auto chronoUserTime = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(&ct));

   std::tm et;
   strptime("1970-01-01 00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &et); //strptime("Thu Jan 1 1970 00:00:00", 
   "%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S", &et);
   auto chronoEpochTime = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(&et));

   auto resultInMS = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(chronoUserTime - 
   chronoEpochTime);

   return resultInMS;
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: Don't cast away `const` when it's not needed (it very rarely is). Do this instead: `const char* dateChar = dateTime.toStdString().c_str();`

Comment: Thank you, I tested it, `const char*` really looks better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why do I have to subtract `chronoUserTime - chronoEpochTime` instead of using `chronoUserTime`  ?

`chronoUserTime` is a point in time, a `time_point`. `milliseconds` is a *duration*. A point in time is not a duration and vice versa. In order to convert a point in time to a duration you need a reference point in time and you've here used the common epoch.

Subtracting one `time_point` from another gives you the *duration* between those `time_point`s - which in your case is `milliseconds` since the epoch.

> Are there any ways, to perfome this in direct way, like in Qt style `addDays`, `setTime`

Yes, you can add a `duration` to a `time_point`:

```
my_time_point += my_duration;
```